# Refactor .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

I have a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file which has a couple of sections for deploying to staging servers - in our small dev team of two, we each have a staging server to test on.  The portion of the file looks like this:

```
...
.deploy: &deploy
  image: docker:stable
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ./deploy.sh

deploy_to_staging_sf:
  <<: *deploy
  only:
    - staging_sf
  tags:
    - staging_sf

deploy_to_staging_ay:
  <<: *deploy
  only:
    - staging_ay
  tags:
    - staging_ay

...
```

The different sections are there to match the different tags for gitlab's CI runners.

If we were to add another developer (or another platform; I was testing deployment to a Raspberry Pi once), I would need to replicate another deploy_to_... section.

I'm just wondering if there's a Gitlab or YAML way to refactor this and make it generic enough so I can add another deployment platform without modifying the file.

Thanks

Comment: could you add some snippets of the `deploy.sh` script, because I think it could be that script that decides where to deploy to (based on the git branch having being updated).

Comment: @flazzarini the script runs `docker-compose` and that uses `${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}` to tag the docker images.  Regarding where to deploy, that is actually based on the `tag` item in the yml it finds an appropriate gitlab runner - the gitlab runner on our staging servers has the tag named the same as the branch.

Comment: I would propose a different solution. Use a centralized [docker registry](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry) and publish different docker images on there. The have a ci job that based on the tag connects to a machine x via ssh and deploys the docker containers (knowingly that you would need to render and copy your docker-compose accordingly to the tag). What do you think of this?